# What are the pros & cons of using an array of structures versus an array of pointers to a structure?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, structure

I'm trying to decide which I should use.

The pros of pointers to structures that I can think off the top of my head.

- Less space wasted if you don't use all elements of your array.
- Less overheard when swapping array elements

Any other pro's/con's for both sides?

Comment: what are your requirements? do you know how many elements will be there in the array at compile time? how frequent is the swapping of elements in the array? how heavy is the structure to make the copying performance of any concern?

Comment: This question is far too vague to be useful. The answer is essentially a whole chapter of "Learn to program in C". It's the equivalent of asking whether about the pros and cons of buying a printer vs buying a monitor. Both output stuff, but they're different.

Comment: @KerrekSB And what is wrong with asking what the differences are in either situation? I've found these answers useful and I hope others who have the question in the future will as well.

Comment: @Michael: Well, it's such a broad question, though, so that there it'd be rather open-ended. There are so many things one can say about this, so it's not clear what a complete answer should look like. It's a perfectly valid question, of course, but SO discourages questions that prompt answers that are tutorial-style and open-ended.

Comment: I have got the exact question while thinking about a project, and found helpful answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few other differences in these approaches:

- The array-of-pointers approach reduces the overhead in resizing the array;
- The array-of-pointers approach gives you an "empty" / "unused" value (NULL).  If this is semantically valid in your application, then this is an advantage (you don't have to alter your `struct` itself to express this);
- The array-of-pointers approach allows multiple elements of the array to refer to the same `struct` rather than a copy.  Again, this is only an advantage if this situation is semantically reasonable for your application;
- The array-of-structures approach provides more locality of reference (`struct`s close together in the array are also close together in memory, which can be a performance advantage in some situations);
- For very large numbers of items, the array-of-structures approach requires a large contiguous block of memory, which may not be available if your process address space has become fragmented.

Answer (score 4):

An downside of using array of pointers, or pointers in general is:

Pointers would (most likely)involve using dynamic memory allocations and that implies manual management of this dynamic memory.
Dynamic memory allocations are little slower than stack allocations.
Also, using dynamic memory is more usage error prone.

Having said that, which one to choose actually depends on:

- How bulky your structures are
- Are number of structures required known at compile time
- How often do you need to swap structures

Comment: Downvoter: Please explain the downvote or refrain from abusing your right to downvote by doing so anonymously.

Comment: Two reasons, dynamic memory is neither slower nor more error prone if you know what you are doing. Static and dynamic memory both have their own pitfalls.

Comment: @LieRyan: Dynamic memory is slower than stack is a pretty well proven fact. As for the error prone, my answer said *More usage error prone* I hope You can make out the difference.

Comment: @AIs: try creating a sorting algorithm that can sort an array of non-trivial structs faster than an array of pointer to struct. With proper use, either can be faster than the other. As to the claim that static memory is less error prone, it is simply untrue, static memory just have their own pitfalls, e.g. you can't return a statically allocated object or you might unnecessarily copy structs or you might (unexpectedly) make copies when calling functions so your modification to an object is not reflected to the caller. Those are common errors if you don't know when to use one or the other.

Answer (score 3):

There's an important distinction to make here, an array of structures needs a contiguous block of memory of the size sizeof(struct)*n, on the other hand, an array of pointers to structures, while it still needs contiguous memory for the array itself, each structure doesn't necessarily have to be next to the other, so the former will need a large block of memory, the later will result in more fragmentation, your choice.

Also, someone mentioned that it is easier to write an array of structures to disk, that's true, since you only need to call write once, with a pointer to the first element and the sizeof(struct)*n, if using an array of pointers you have to loop and write each element separately.

Edit: and of course you will need to allocate each structure, in a loop, for an array of pointers. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to write the data to disk, or send it out on a socket, or place it in shared memory (all very common tasks in embedded, realtime applications), an array can be slightly simpler.

And arrays avoid the use of `malloc().` But they often need `realloc(),` which as caf points out can be a problem if the array is big and the memory space is fragmented.  Of course, `realloc()` is not applicable to arrays in [`.bss,`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) or in `.text.`  I look forward to the other answers.  Good question.

Comment: Keep in mind that `realloc` is for dynamic memory allocated via `malloc`, not for arrays declared on the stack or in statically allocated memory ...

Comment: Like Als, I also just received a strange downvote. I agree this may not be be world's most stellar answer, but come on...

Comment: @Jason: Good warning.  One can't expand `.bss,` afaik, and I would hope nobody would ever want a `realloca()` function!

Answer (score 1):

One possible con is that working with pointers is more overhead for you, the programmer. You need to decide what your project goals are.

If you're not planning to do a lot of sorting and swapping, and you have plenty of memory and don't plan on maxing it out, then you need to ask yourself if it's worth the headache of using pointers.

Comment: I guess the downvoter thinks that we should always do things the hardest way possible even if we're merely dealing with an array of 12 elements?  Want to elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

An array of pointers will require space to store the pointers as well as the structures.  On the other hand, if different structures hold different, but unchanging, amounts of meaningful data, using pointers to the structures would allow one to allocate different amounts of space for them.  The space savings from this could in some cases more than outweigh the cost of the extra pointers.

Using an array of pointers to access structures would in many cases require an extra table-lookup step for each structure access, while using an array of structures would require an extra multiply operation.  On many newer architectures, multiplies are cheaper than table lookups, but on some smaller or older architectures the reverse is true.  Also, some smaller or older architectures may have difficulties with objects that straddle certain memory boundaries.  Allocating an array of eight 20-byte struct pointers may be possible even on an architecture where it would be impossible to allocate an array of more than 80 bytes.